# using array elements to perform calculations

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

I am trying to create a hashing function. The algorithm requires me to take each letter of the string and convert it to ASCII; multiply it by a number based on its position in the string (for example Input is STACK; ASCII for 'S' would be 344, multiply that value by 9^9 then ASCII for 'T' would be 347 multiply that value by 8^8.. etc); and then add the values together.

I understand how to access the values in the array to create the sum and can convert them to ASCII. I don't understand how I would access the array to perform the calculations in-between.

I also get an "assertion failed error", when I build the program. I looked up the error and it says it has something to do with bad calls, however I can't see any bad calls in my code.

my code is below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input ;
    int finalanswer = 0;

    cout << "Enter your first name please : " ;

    cin >> input;

    cout << "Your name is " << input ;

    for (int x=0; x=input.size(); x++)
    {   
        finalanswer += input[x];

        cout << finalanswer ;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't remove the problem from the question. Fixing the code confuses everyone else reading the post later.

Comment: @BoPersson that problem was not the reason i made the post i found the error after i proof read the question, so i removed the minor error so focus was placed on the original question

Comment: @BoPersson I also wonder: What's the correct protocol for the OP? Ask a new question?

Comment: It's really up to the two of you. :-) When you have answers to the question actually asked, it is usually better to ask a new question rather than change the old one. In this case, the value of solving the typo isn't really that great. If @Daniel can answer the new question, we *could* also adapt the question to that.

Comment: my problem is that making a new post will get shut down due to people calling it a duplicate

Comment: @JohnDevaney: The algorithm still makes no sense. `'S'` is not 344 (ASCII is only 0-127) and for the `9^9`, `8^8`, etc.: What happens when the string has 20 characters?

Comment: i was using those values as an example and the string will be set by me i am using a 8 character string

Comment: @BoPersson: Agreed, the typo isn't worth a Q&A to be preserved for future generations :) Maybe OP can just delete this question and ask a new one? That way it won't be called a dup. It's just that I can't *answer* the new question as long as I don't *understand* the new question :)

Comment: so the calculation would be something like : (104*7^7) + (99*6^6) + (52 * 5^5) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the for-loop is wrong, it should be

```
for(int x=0; x < input.size(); x++)
```

With your code, the second time the body of the loop is executed `x` is `input.size()` and that is too large to access `input[x]` - leading to the error you see.

---

I'm not sure I understand the intended algorithm 100%, but that might help:

```
int myPow(int x, int p)
{
  if (p == 0) return 1;
  if (p == 1) return x;
  return x * myPow(x, p-1);
}
```

and then for the loop:

```
for(int x=0; x < input.size(); x++)
{
    finalanswer += input[x] * myPow(9-x);

    cout << finalanswer ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that i realized that after i posted the question. any idea on the how i would tackle accessing the array to complete the individual calculations.

Comment: @JohnDevaney: Edited the answer, tried to solve the algorithm problem.

Comment: thanks this put me on the right track and i found the correct answer